# Google geocoder finds Georgia state, not country

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a global-scale map with a search bar that allows the user to search for a country, and when they click the button it will zoom in to the country they searched for (using the Google Geocoder). My issue is that when I pass 'Georgia' to the geocoder, it finds the state of Georgia, not the country. Is there any way to avoid this? How do I specify the country of Georgia, and ignore the USA's Georgia?

Try it out here: https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/csterling/web/practice.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked for me and I did the following:

Clicked in the "Search by country" and instead of typing just "Georgia" I put "Country Georgia" and it works.

Since the Google maps geocoder is just like a google search, it's "smart". ;)

Comment: Thanks! I just added an if statement to see if the input equals 'Georgia' and have it change it to 'Country Georgia'

Answer (score 0):

I used "Georgia Country".  [Example](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html)